# Why $\int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{\sin(x)}{x} \: dx = \int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{\sin^{2}(x)}{x^{2}} \: dx$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

In an exercise, I saw the following equality :

$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{\sin(x)}{x} \: dx = \int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{\sin^{2}(x)}{x^{2}} \: dx $$

At first, I was surprised by this equality. It is very easy to prove using integration by parts. Still, I don't find this explanation "intuitive". Is there a more intuitive explanation ?

Comment: The square is making those values of the function a bit smaller (the ones that are of absolute value $\leq1$) or larger (the ones with absolute value $\geq1$). But some are positive and some are negative. Like what happens in $5-3=2=4-2$. Cool would be a geometric interpretation, but I don't have it.

Comment: Thanks ! I would also be interested in a geometric explanation (if there is one).

Comment: Also interesting: Are there other nice examples with $\int_a^bf(x)\,\mathrm dx=\int_a^bf^2(x)\,\mathrm dx$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, in general,

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \, f(x)$$

is equal to the Fourier transform of $f$, $\hat{f}(k)$, at $k=0$.  In this case, the FT of $\sin{x}/x$ is

$$\hat{f}(k) = \begin{cases} \pi & |k| \le 1\\0&|k| \gt 1 \end{cases}$$

so that the integral on the left is $(1/2) \pi$.

To consider the integral on the right, we use the fact that the Fourier transform of a product of two functions is equal to $1/(2 \pi)$ times the convolution of the transforms of the functions.  In this case, the transform would be the above rectangle function convolved with itself.  But because we are evaluating the integral on the RHS, which is the FT at $k=0$, we just need the convolution at $k=0$, which is just the integral of  square of the above rectangle function, or $2 \pi^2/(2 \pi)$, so that the integral on the RHS is, again $\pi/2$.

The salient fact here is that the transforms of the above integrands are based on rectangle functions, which exhibit a form of invariance in their product.

Comment: Can we talk about the FT of $x \, \mapsto \, \frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ since it is not a $L^{1}(\mathbb{R})$ function ? Even though, it is in $L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: Alternatively, (but very similarly) we could see use Plancherel's theorem on the right hand side and show that the rect function squared is again the rect function.

Comment: @jibounet: yes, you may evaluate the integral and show it converges by Jordan's Lemma.

Comment: Thank you for your answer !

Answer (score 0):

You can generalize this result using the residue theorem of complex analysis and the theorem of the upper half plane, then you don't need partial integration, but this is the way, calculate as much as you can and see at the ending, that it is the same.

Don't think too much about this problem, because it's just coincidence.

Comment: Nothing in mathematics at this level is mere coincidence.  And if we just thought that way and brushed off interesting patterns, we'd still be dragging our mates away by their hair.

Answer (score 0):

If you use integration by parts with $ u=\sin(x)^2 $, then we have

$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{\sin^{2}(x)}{x^{2}} \: dx =  \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{2\sin(x)\cos(x)}{x}dx = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(2x)}{x}dx =I. $$

Now, use the change of variables $2x=t$, you get the equality of the two integrals

$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(t)}{t}dt. $$

Comment: You're right ! But I already know this method. I was looking for another explanation.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention it explicitly.

Comment: @jibounet: Sorry, it is my fault. I did not pay attention to it.